# Get number of occurences containing a specific number in combinations of N digits?

Tags: combinatorics, functions

If I have all the combinations of 3 digits (000 to 999) I want to count how many results contain the digit 4:

```
456
104
404
...
```

For 4XX there are 100, for X4X it gets hard to calculate and they will be collide with the hundreds, so I totally don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $4??$, $?4?$ and $??4$ you'll have exactly the same amount of possibilities. But note that codes like $44?$ will get counted multiple times this way. A more proper way to count is to see that
$$\binom 31 \cdot 9^2 + \binom 32 \cdot 9^1 + \binom 33 \cdot 9^0\\
=3\cdot 81 + 3\cdot 9 + 1\cdot 1 = 271$$
Will get the desired result (*why*?)

---

Efficient enumeration would find them as follows:

```
4[^4][^4] -> 81
[^4]4[^4] -> 81
[^4][^4]4 -> 81
44[^4]    -> 9
4[^4]4    -> 9
[^4]44    -> 9
444       -> 1
-----------------
Total        271
```

`[^4]` denotes any non-4 digit (9 total).